# Table transformation with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I have a table called df. This table contains three columns (Code,Description and Rate).

[image]

```
#CODE

df<-data.frame(
  Code=c("01","0101","0101 21 00 00","0101 29","0101 29 10 00","0101 29 
          90 00","0101 30 00 00","0101 90 00 00","NA","0102 21","0102 21 10 
          00","0102 21 30 00","0102 21 90 00"),
  Description=c("LIVE ANIMALS", "Live horses, asses, mules","Live horses, 
                asses, mules and hinnies","Pure-bred breeding horses","Live 
                horses (excl. pure-bred for breeding)","Horses for 
                slaughter","Live horses (excl. for slaughter, pure-bred for 
                breeding)","Live asses","Live mules and hinnies","Live 
                bovine animals","Pure-bred cattle for breeding","Pure-bred 
                breeding heifers female bovines that have never 
                calved","Pure-bred breeding cows (excl. heifers)"),
  Rate=c("NA","NA","5","NA","5","10","15","7","NA","NA","10","15","20"))
```

So my intention is to make subset of upper table which will only contain field of column Code which have 10-digits and calculate average. This means the code should only extract rows with 10-digits codes (0101 21 00 00,0101 29 10 00, 0101 29 90 00,0101 30 00 00,0101 90 00 00,0102 21 10 00,0102 21 30 00 and 0102 21 90 00) like table below.Average of column Rate is 2,75.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to transform this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the spaces from the codes and then count the characters. That lets use `filter` to 10-digit codes only. We can then add a `summarise` if we want the mean (note that it is not 2.75)

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Code = c("01", "0101", "0101 21 00 00", "0101 29", "0101 29 10 00", "0101 29 90 00", "0101 30 00 00", "0101 90 00 00", "NA", "0102 21", "0102 21 10 00", "0102 21 30 00", "0102 21 90 00"), Description = c("LIVE ANIMALS", "Live horses, asses, mules", "Live horses,  asses, mules and hinnies", "Pure-bred breeding horses", "Live horses (excl. pure-bred for breeding)", "Horses for slaughter", "Live horses (excl. for slaughter, pure-bred for breeding)", "Live asses", "Live mules and hinnies", "Live  bovine animals", "Pure-bred cattle for breeding", "Pure-bred breeding heifers female bovines that have never calved", "Pure-bred breeding cows (excl. heifers)"), Rate = c("NA", "NA", "5", "NA", "5", "10", "15", "7", "NA", "NA", "10", "15", "20"))
df %>%
  filter(Code %>% str_remove_all("\\s") %>% str_length %>% `==`(10))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   Code         Description                                            Rate 
#>   <chr>        <chr>                                                  <chr>
#> 1 0101 21 00 … Live horses,  asses, mules and hinnies                 5    
#> 2 0101 29 10 … Live horses (excl. pure-bred for breeding)             5    
#> 3 0101 29 90 … Horses for slaughter                                   10   
#> 4 0101 30 00 … Live horses (excl. for slaughter, pure-bred for breed… 15   
#> 5 0101 90 00 … Live asses                                             7    
#> 6 0102 21 10 … Pure-bred cattle for breeding                          10   
#> 7 0102 21 30 … Pure-bred breeding heifers female bovines that have n… 15   
#> 8 0102 21 90 … Pure-bred breeding cows (excl. heifers)                20

df %>%
  filter(Code %>% str_remove_all("\\s") %>% str_length %>% `==`(10)) %>%
  summarise(mean_rate = mean(as.integer(Rate)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   mean_rate
#>       <dbl>
#> 1      10.9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>